# Move the contents of one file to another

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have created two `files`, one of them is the line less(temporary), and I would like to delete the original, and the contents of a temporary replacement for the original . `renameTo` does not work, I do not know why: / or some completely different way to go about it?

***Remove line :***

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) listViewZaznam.getAdapter();

    FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(String.valueOf(oldfile));

    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    FileOutputStream fileout = openFileOutput(String.valueOf(newfile), MODE_APPEND);
    OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);


    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(removethisline)) {
            adapter.remove(removethisline);
            continue;
        }
        outputWriter.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    }

    outputWriter.close();
    bufferedReader.close();
    newfile.renameTo(oldfile); // ??

}
```

***Read from file***

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) listViewZaznam.getAdapter();
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput(String.valueOf(oldfile));

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String drziaciString = "";


            while ((drziaciString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {


                adapter.add(drziaciString);
                listViewZaznam.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Rename will only work on Linux (Android), if the files are in the same file system, it is mounted read-write and you have write access to the source and target directories.

So for example, a rename will fail if one file is on the SD card and the other on internal storage.

Could something like that be happening in your case?

It would be interesting to check whether you can delete the files as a test.

Comment: No , both files are in internal storage and i can delete files... i use deleteFile(file), or exist some mode where i can rewrite file, but not only one line (i think MODE_PRIVATE)?

Comment: Are you using absolute paths?

Comment: `File oldfile = new File("trasa.txt");` no

Comment: Could you try it with absolute paths? Otherwise isn't there a dependency on the cwd?

Comment: Problem solved, remove line  ->delete old file -> copy from new to old -> delete new file :) Thank you for your effort